# Puedo hacer rooms dinamicas con socket.io

Tags: php, javascript, socket.io

Tengo un servidor node.js y con socket.io funcionando, del lado del cliente tengo un index.html donde introduces el usuario y escojes el room al que quieres conectarte. Seria posible generar las rooms dinámicamente.
Yo habia pensado, en lugar de llamar al index.html, crear un index.php y así poder generar dinámicamente las rooms pero no me funciona. Parece que el servidor no acepta index.php
Gracias.

Usando el mismo server.js, hacer un index.php variable uno para el Propietario y otro para los Comerciales:

Chat Propietario:

```
<form action="chat.html">                                                                                                                 <div class="form-control">                                                                                     
<label for="username">Nombre</label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username..." required />                                
</div>                                                                                                                        
<div class="form-control">                                                                                     
<label for="room">Propietario</label>                                                                 
<select name="room" id="room">                                                                       
<option value="Cristina">Cristina</option>                                                      
</select>                                                                                                             
</div>                                                                                                               
<button type="submit" class="btn">Unirse al Chat</button>                           </form>
```

Chat Comerciales:

```
<form action="chat.html">                                                                                                                 <div class="form-control">                                                                                     
<label for="username">Nombre</label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username..." required />                                
</div>                                                                                                                        
<div class="form-control">                                                                                     
<label for="room">Comerciales</label>                                                                 
<select name="room" id="room">                                                                       
<option value="Jordi">Jordi</option>                                                      
<option value="Pepe">Pepe</option>                                                      
</select>                                                                                                             
</div>                                                                                                               
<button type="submit" class="btn">Unirse al Chat</button>                           </form>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar al menos un ejemplo de lo que intentas hacer? ¿Qué son para ti las *rooms dinámicas*? ¿Puedes poner ejemplo o descripción de una *room* (sala) dinámica? Tu pregunta, tal como está redactada, se basa totalmente en opiniones. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razon que no me he explicado bien.

Comment: Por favor, todos esos comentarios hazlos en la pregunta, haciendo clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta